# How to queue up batch operations in AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: afnetworking

I have this function which calls a GET method on AFHTTPRequestOperationManager:

```
var request:NSMutableURLRequest = ParseAPIClient.sharedClient.GET(className, parameters: parameters, success: { (operation:AFHTTPRequestOperation!, response:AnyObject!) -> Void in
       if response.isKindOfClass(NSDictionary) {
              self.writeJSONResponse(response, toDiskForClassWithName:className)
       } else { NSLog("something happened") }
   }, failure: { (operation:AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
       NSLog("Request for class %@ failed with error: %@", className, error)
   })
```

This generates a request uses that request to create an AFHTTPRequestOperation.  That operation is returned in that method along with a response to the request.  The block passed into it writes the response to disk.

In my old AF1.x code, I would then use:

```
SDAFParseAPIClient.sharedClient.enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:operations progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfCompletedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
            } completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
                if (!toDelete) {
                    self.processJSONDataRecordsIntoCoreData
                } else {
                    self.processJSONDataRecordsForDeletion
                }
            }];
```

method to take those operations created above and do something else afterwards.  Iow, I would take the data written to disk and parse it with those self.processJSONDataRecords... methods.

Im not sure what would be the new equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent functionality in AFNetworking 2.0 is provided by [`AFURLConnectionOperation +batchOfRequestOperations:progressBlock:completionBlock:`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.4.1/Classes/AFURLConnectionOperation.html#//api/name/batchOfRequestOperations:progressBlock:completionBlock:).

The difference here is that the developer is ultimately responsible for enqueuing the array of batched operations, using `NSOperationQueue -addOperations:waitUntilFinished:`.

Comment: Thanks.  I also noticed that that function returns an array instead of being void.  Hence I have to take that array and queue it up.